# Access Denied when trying to run a Loop in IE using AHK

Tags: internet-explorer, element, autohotkey

I'm trying to write a script that goes in to a link on a website, navigates to the settings, alters the settings and then goes back to the main page to click on the next link and repeat till all the links are clicked.

Everything works for the first loop but when it goes back to the main page to click the next link i get a "access denied" error.

```
wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
wb.Visible := true

wb.Navigate(path)

IELoad(wb)

Elements := {}
count := 0

Elements := wb.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

Loop % Elements.length {

ComObjError(false)
    While (value == "") {
    value := Elements.25.innerText
    Sleep 100
    }
ComObjError(true)

Elements[25].click()

IELoad(wb)
sleep, 2000
wb.document.getElementsByTagName("a")[28].click() 
IELoad(wb)
sleep, 2000
wb.document.All.project_custom_field_values_142.value := "North West"

ClickElementWithThisText("Projects", wb.document, "a")
if A_Index > Elements.length
    break
}



IELoad(wb)    
{
    If !wb    
    Return False
    Loop    
        Sleep,100
    Until (wb.busy)
    Loop    
        Sleep,100
    Until (!wb.busy)
    Loop    
        Sleep,100
    Until (wb.Document.Readystate = "Complete")
Return True
}


ClickElementWithThisText(text, document, tagName)
{
    elements := document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)
    Loop % elements.length
        if (elements[A_Index - 1].innerText = text)
        {
            elements[A_Index - 1].click()
            break
        }
}
```